# How to display bitmap to jpeg formate in iTextSharp pdf in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, itext, bitmapimage

I'm converting the text in the barcode which working fine. Then converting the barcode to bitmap, is working fine. But instead of saving the barcode, I want to display it on the pdf.
Here I'm using iTextSharp for Pdf & barcode generation.
Below is my code:-

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128
                            {
                                CodeType = Barcode.CODE128,
                                ChecksumText = true,
                                X = 1.1f,
                                BarHeight = 20,
                                GenerateChecksum = true,
                                StartStopText = true,
                                Code = "Angular 9"
                            };

Bitmap bms = new Bitmap(code128.CreateDrawingImage(Color.Black, Color.White));
```

**I don't want to Save. But directly display in my pdf**

```
bb.Save("E:/API/MyBarCode.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

**Appending my html in pdf like this.Here img src I'm creating dynamic filename. in img src I want to pass the value directly **
`sb.Append("<img src='" + dta.Rows[0]["PATH"].ToString() + "'></img>");`

So can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show your barcode in the PDF in the following way (no need to create intermediate bitmap):

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128 { ... };
code128.placeBarcode(canvas, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
```